# I want to get the string which is before @ and after any other special character or blank space in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, split

I would like to split the string in SQL sever and get the value which is before @ and after any other special character.

```
Example 1: I have a string     
abc.123.vet@xyz.com     
Expected output: vet

Example 2: aaa@yy.com  
Expected output: aaa

Example 3: aaa bte@yy.com  
Expected output: bte
```

I have tried:

Code snippet #1:

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(100)
SET @email = 'firstname.lastname@email.com'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@email, 0, CHARINDEX('@', @email))
```

Code snippet #2:

```
DECLARE @emai1l VARCHAR(100)
SET @emai1l = 'first.name.lastname@email.com'

SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@emai1l, 0, CHARINDEX('@', @emai1l)), 0, CHARINDEX('.', @emai1l))
```

Comment: What do you define as a "special character"? Anything that isn't a alphanumeric?

Comment: yes, non alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is not optimal for this type of string manipulation.  However, here is one method:

```
select t.str, v.str,
       right(v.str,
             patindex('%[, .]%', reverse(v.str) + ' ') - 1
            ) as result
from (values ('abc.123.vet@xyz.com'), ('aaa@yy.com'), ('aaa bte@yy.com')
     ) t(str) cross apply
     (values (left(t.str, charindex('@', t.str) - 1))
     ) v(str) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a8091d2455b21276a89b4f13ec5fd31) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am tying to fetch vet as the output from example 1 : abc.123.vet@xyz.com

Comment: @ShreyaS . . . That is a simple tweak to the logic.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.